# why Pthread virtual memory usage is different from OpenMP?

Tags: parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp

[image]

I am calculating pi with `OpenMP` and `Pthread`.

```
for (i=0; i<num_steps; i++) {
        x = (i+0.5) * step;
        sum += 4.0/(1.0 + x*x);
    }
```

As you see in the graph, the usage of the virtual memory of OpenMP is growing proportionally. However, Pthread has funny usage. Once Pthread allocates big portion and increases only once (16392KB which is double size of stack maximum 8192KB). Why does Pthread consumes more usage at first then remains almost same?

=============edit ====================

I use GCC 4.8.5 compiler and have Pthread code. Memory usage unit is KB.

```
void *count_sum(void *myID){
        int i;
        double local_sum = 0.0, x = 0.0;
        double st = 1.0/((double)NUM_ITER);
        int start = ((int)myID) * (NUM_ITER / NUM_THREAD);
        int end = start + (NUM_ITER / NUM_THREAD);

        printf("myID = %d startPos = %d endPos = %d \n", (int) myID, start, end);

        for(i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
                x = (i + 0.25) * st;
                local_sum += 4.0/(x*x + 1);
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
        global_sum += local_sum;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct timeval t1, t2;
    double elapsedTime;
    int numSlots, myVersion = 1;

    NUM_THREAD = atoi(argv[1]);
    NUM_ITER = atoi(argv[2]);

    // pthread stuff
    int i, rc;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREAD];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *status;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++ ) {
          rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, count_sum, (void *)i);
          if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
          }
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    for(i=0; i<NUM_THREAD; i++) {
         rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
         if (rc) {
           printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
           exit(-1);
         }
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    processMem_t myMem; 
    GetProcessMemory(&myMem);
    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0; //sec to ms
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0; // us to ms
    printf("Memory usage, %u, %u, PTHREAD, DATA, %d, %s, %f, Num_Thread, %d, Num_Iter, %d, SUM, %f\n", myMem.virtualMem, myMem.physicalMem, myVersion, getenv("SLURM_NTASKS"),  elapsedTime, NUM_THREAD, NUM_ITER, global_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you measure, what is the unit in your graph, which compiler/OpenMP runtime.

Comment: You need to show more code. How did you set up the threads with pthreads? Can you make a simple working example that we can try?

Comment: @Zulan  I edited. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: @Zboson I added my Pthread code